# Import signpost code names for Points of Interest instrument in Xcode for iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, instruments

I'm building out a waterfall for our application's tasks and want to view them in instruments with the helpful `kdebug_signpost` API. And I want to associate the codes with meaningful names like:

[image]

Is there a way I can generate this template programmatically? If I save the template to disk, it results in what looks like a `plist` file, but it's not at all obvious how to insert `code <==> string` pairs into it.

I'd love to have `import singpost code names` option or write a script to do this as my application is going to have many of these codes and changing them manually will become burdensome.

Comment: Theoretically, you could use Automator (or similar tool) to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xcode 10 instruments has some new functionality to allow for passing names through the API to the tool. Thanks Apple!

[WWDC: Measuring Performance Using Logging](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/405/)